# Como passar o script do html para o css?

Tags: javascript, html

Alguns sites como o [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/), ao fornecerem algum código, mantem o script na mesma página do código em html.

Como posso passar tudo que está no script abaixo para meu .jsp?

```
<div>
    <div class="container">
        <h2>Rubricas cadastradas</h2>
        <input class="form-control" id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Pesquisar...">
        <table class="table table-sm">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
                <tr>
                    <th>Categoria</th>
                    <th>Rubrica</th>
                    <th>Valor</th>
                    <th>Excluir</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="myTable">
                <c:forEach items="${rubricas}" var="rubrica">
                    <tr>
                        <td> --- </td>
                        <td> ${rubrica.nome}</td>
                        <td> ${rubrica.getValorTotal()}</td>
                        <td style="width: 16%">
                            <form action="excluirProjeto" method="POST">
                                <input type="hidden" class="form-control" value="${projeto.id}" name="projeto_id">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-link"> <img src="../img/excluir.png" alt="Logo" style="width:100%;"> </button>
                            </form> 
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>
            </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
            var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
            $("#myTable tr").filter(function() {
                $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Uma pergunta só para não ficar dúvidas... jsp = ?

Comment: @brnTwp [jsp](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Pages)

Comment: O que eu não entendi foi o título da pergunta (Como passar o script do html para o css?), passar para .jsp ou para o css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A melhor prática para trabalhar com scripts é utilizar um arquivo externo e chama-lo dentro de uma tag `script`

O código abaixo deve estar em um arquivo separado. Por exemplo: `script.js`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $("#myTable tr").filter(function() {
            $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
        });
    });
});
```

E no seu `html`, você chama o arquivo da seguinte forma:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

No Atributo `"src"` deve conter o caminho para o seu arquivo `.js`

Também é uma boa prática chamar a tag script na ultima linha, antes de fechar a tag `</body>`

Comment: No meu sistema eu estou usando um arquivo base que está com todos os imports inclusive esse do javascript. Tentei dessa forma colocando o script do html lá e chamando no base mas mesmo assim não foi (e nem mesmo testanto com um import nessa mesma página).

Comment: Se você reparar, o script usa jquery, provavelmente no código que copiou do site chama a biblioteca do jquery de alguma forma que não fica visível no código. Veja no console qual o erro que aparece

Comment: Você pode utilizar um CDN que a própria comunidade do jquery disponibiliza: <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

Esse link deve vir ANTES da sua tag script